# Testing @nuxtjs/axios using avajs

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, ava

I have not been able to figure out how to use avajs to test @nuxtjs/axios.  Does anyone have a working example?

Here's a stub of what I tried:
import axios from '@nuxtjs/axios';
localVue.use(axios);

When I do this, I get the following error:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'axios' of undefined

axiosModule (node_modules/@nuxtjs/axios/lib/module.js:8:43)